# How to change hover css with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I tried this code

```
var btn = $('<button>Button</button>');
$('body').append(btn);
btn.hover().css('background-color', 'red');
```

But it does not work

Comment: You can't call `hover` like that. You have to create an `event `. Like, `btn.hover(function() {});`

Comment: You should just do this in CSS. `button:hover { background: red; }`

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: "It does not work"... why?

Answer (score 3):

You could just use the native `css :hover` selector.

```css
button {
  border: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button>Click!</button>
```

Comment: I need to change properties dynamically